# Applying for French Schengen visa with hotel booking confirmation e-mail

Tags: visas, france, bookings, hotels, schengen-visas

I am applying for a France short stay visa in July. All my documents are ready but I am a little confused about my hotel booking. I confirmed my hotel booking via a phone call directly to hotel and they send me an ordinary email with a confirmation code, check-in and check-out date and my name. Is this OK? Because my visa advisor told me that you should book through booking.com, that is more reliable and easy to confirm for the visa officer. In my case the visa officer will not be able to check my booking online if he needs to check it; only via call or email. Please, can anyone guide me on this issue?

Comment: What you have, a direct reservation with the hotel, should be just as reliable, and may be even more so. It's in France, and French officials can easily check, should that be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

A direct reservation with the hotel should be just as reliable, and may be even more so. You are not required to use any specific online tool to reserve accommodations. As what you have is in France, and French officials can easily check, that should satisfy what is necessary.